# .NET EntityFramework Error when enabling migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-migrations

everybody!

I'm trying to update my database using CF. When I execute the "enable-migrations" command in the PMC it says:

```
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet
```

Followed by a stack trace.

I've been looking for it on-line, and i've tried a bunch of things I came into, but none worked. I have lost the track of those attempts, so I'm quite lost and confused.

I don't know what can be causing this, so please, ask me to post more information if needed.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have just realized that this same error comes up every time I attempt to query the database, regardless of the query.

Comment: I need your code, your config and your stacktrace.

Comment: A friend of mine solved it. I was trying to update the database with a new entity, that had a custom class inside with an other class that was not added to the context.